# firebase not converting to string

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase

Firebase is not sending snapshot as a string, when I click `"href="javascript:set('+snapshot.name()+')"` I'll get

> Uncaught ReferenceError: JRzwdm2xzLvGG8BB_OZ is not defined

JRzwdm2xzLvGG8BB_OZ is the actual reference of the snapshot. But since it's not sent as a string, I get the error.

Does anyone know a fix for this or how to convert this to a string?

```
var ref = new Firebase('https://checkme.firebaseio.com/profiles/'+user);
ref.on('child_added', function(snapshot){
  $("#profileList").append('<div class=" wk-progress tm-membr"><div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2"><div class="tm-avatar"><img src="'+snapshot.val().image+'" alt=""></div></div><div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4"><span class="tm">'+snapshot.val().firstName+'</span></div><div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6"><a **href="javascript:set('+snapshot.name()+')"** class="btn btn-info">CheckMe</a></div></div>'); 
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The html that you are building will end up looking like:

```
<a href="javascript:set(JRzwdm2xzLvGG8BB_OZ)" class="btn btn-info">CheckMe</a>
```

in which case it looks for a variable called `JRzwdm2xzLvGG8BB_OZ` whereas what you really want is for it to use the string `'JRzwdm2xzLvGG8BB_OZ'`. You need to add some quotes around `snapshot.name()` to make that happen:

```
'<a href="javascript:set(\''+snapshot.name()+'\')" class="btn btn-info">CheckMe</a>'`
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, simply using `JSON.stringify(snapshot.name())` instead of `snapshot.name()` should do what you want.